# How to precisely get a listitem from ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listitem

I have set up a list view in which ListItems are filled by ArrayAdapter. Also have setup an OnClickListener() to receive click on any of the listitem as follows:

```
private TextView prev = null;

final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            if(prev != null)
            {
                prev.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            }

            TextView textView = listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.drawertext);
// drawertext is ID of text inside list items
            prev = textView;
            textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);;
        }
    });
```

Aim is to change the typeface of clicked item to bold and to revert the typeface for item which was previously selected (using **prev** for that purpose).
Problem is, when the user clicks an item, along with that listitem, typeface of few other listitems is also getting changed.

I think the reason might be 'sliding window' concept as the adapter recycles views for listview..not sure. Anyways, how to prevent this, and rather uniquely identify each of the list item on click.

Comment: try it by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` before changing typeface

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK still no use :( what is it supposed to do? (btw data once loaded need not change, so i guess it might not fit here)

Comment: You might run into an issue with View Recycling, but you need to tell the TextView that it should update. Callings textView.invalidate() should do the trick.

Comment: @AChez9 should I call it before changing typeface or after?

Comment: After. I might be wrong and the previous commenter had it right, but call it after your update.

Comment: @AChez9 hmm..still no luck

Comment: Did you update your question? Maybe I am seeing things... Like you said, you are seeing this issue due to the view recycling. You're best bet would be to create a custom adapter, and within that adapter, have a variable that holds an id (or list of ids) for the view(s) that was clicked (position, UID of the Objects, etc.), then in bindView, check if that view is the one that is clicked, and update the textView accordingly.